# how to create a cron job for running a perl script at a fixed time of day every day on free bsd?

Tags: cron, freebsd

I have perl script which I want to be executed at a fixed time of day everyday using a cron job ?

Answer (score 1):

> $ crontab -e 1 2 3 4 5   /path_to_your_perl_script

save it with :wq

> Where,
>
> ```
> 1: Minute (0-59)
> 2: Hours (0-23)
> 3: Day (0-31)
> 4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
> 5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
> /path_to_your_perl_script  - Script or command name to schedule
> ```

Comment: I had already done this . Is there anything else that needs to be done aprt from this ?